# How to identify 64-bit Microsoft Office components?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

I need to install [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920), so that I can import Excel 2016 files with SQL Server Management Studio.

So I go that link, download both 32 and 64 bit versions (why not).  I try to install 64 bit version, it tells me that `You cannot install 64-bit version ... because you have 32-bit Office products installed`

Fair enough, so I try to install the 32-bit version and it tells me that `You cannot install 32-bit version ... because you have 64-bit Office products installed`.  Maddening.

So I check various Office products in the Task Manager and they are all 32-bit.   So how do I identify which Office component is 64 bit so that I can blow it away?  I looked in the %TEMP% and found log files generated by the installation, but it doesn't say anything beyond the error message.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall Office 2016 and reinstall it?

Comment: If you have the 32-bit version of Office installed you should be using AccessDatabaseEngine.exe.  I have confirmed with multiple versions of Office that `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe`` will install on x86 and x64 versions of Windows with a 32-bit version of Office installed.  However, my suggestion, is to reinstall Office and install the 64-bit installation and simply use ` or `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe` instead

Comment: @Ramhound I can't reinstall because I would then have to go deal with IT trying to find the installation, pointless questions like what are you trying to do, etc...  This would legit take a week at least.

Comment: I assume you have asked your IT department to install this application for you?  I have a 64-bit installation of Office installed, doesn't matter what version, the download you linked to installed without a problem.  It is possible, but extremely hard, to have 32-bit and 64-bit Office products.  Without knowing what other Office programs you have installed I couldn't say if that is your problem.  You really should get help from your IT department.

Answer (score 0):

The best route might be to clean Office out completely and reinstall from scratch.

Use both methods listed in
[Uninstall Office from a PC](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US),
one after the other:

- Uninstall Office from the Control Panel
- Completely uninstall Office with the
  [uninstall support tool](https://aka.ms/SaRA-officeUninstallFromPC)

Comment: The medicine is worse than the patient's condition.

Comment: Why? Uninstallation will save you time.

Comment: I would then have to go deal with IT trying to find the installation.  That is likely to result in delays, pointless questions, etc...

Comment: There isn't much to do if you're not the admin of your computer. You can perhaps create a virtual machine with Windows where you are the admin and work within it, to avoid going through your IT dept.